# What does NHP in a hp product name mean

Tags: hard-drive, sas

Looking for SAS Hard Drives, I found to drives different in only one point (as it seems to me): One has the letters "NHP" in its product name, the other one doesn't. What does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**N**on **H**ot-**P**lug, not designed for removal and replacement whilst the system is still running.

Business servers (other than entry-level SME servers) generally are specified with Hot-Plug drives to reduce server down-time.